# Can't set url inside css in codeigniter

Tags: php, css

```
.ico-del{
    content:icon;
    icon:url(http://localhost/reg_&_logins/assets/images/cross.png);}
```

I tried this in codeigniter, But it didn't work, is there any way to set this url.

Comment: Is the image path correct?

Comment: Even if it did work.. once you click that upload button.. :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the image URL in the content tag:

```
.ico-del {
    content:url(path/image.gif);
}
```

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_content_url

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your css file in `assets` folder, you can try this:

```
.ico-del{
content:icon;
icon:url("images/cross.png");
}
```